# OAuth require our website to have an account?

Tags: oauth, twitter-oauth, google-oauth, facebook-oauth

Just need a very basic detail clearified.

If I'm trying to implement au OAuth authentification system for my website, it mean my website is REQUIRED to have a facebook, google and twitter account ?

For example: I have no intention for my website to have a twitter presence, but I want twitter users to be able to use OAuth to login on my website without registering manually.

I really need to open a twitter account to get my clientID and secret key code ?

Comment: For Twitter and Facebook, you must have an account to sign up for an OAuth key. For Google you do not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it looks like you need a Twitter account in order to create a Twitter application, but it doesn't have to be an account for your website. For instance, if I want to create a "Sign in with Twitter" button on my, page, I can just log into the dev site using my personal account and create an application. Follow the steps [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/implementing-sign-twitter). In particular following the "[application settings](https://dev.twitter.com/apps)" link will prompt you to login, and then you can create an application.

Facebook likewise requires you to have an account and create an application. They then provide API keys that can be used in the OAuth login flow. They have two ways to get a token: a server side flow that provides a longer lived token, and a client side that gives a shorter one. For more details see [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/).

With Google, if you use their OAuth 1.0 flow, you can do a login without creating an application (https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth). However, it looks like their preferred way is their OAuth 2.0 flow through Google+. See [this page](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login).

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I want to do. It's not even an "application" per say, it's really just a sign-on to my website.

Comment: @FMaz008 marking this as the answer would be appreciated. If you need more info, I'll be happy to expand a bit.

Comment: The only thing that bug me is that your answer does not address Google and Facebook. So far I figured out that google require us to register the return url (redirect_uri_mismatch) or something, so to me, it force us to have an account... at least. Yes, I'd appreciate if you could extend a bit, what you said isn't wrong, but I'm still not sure I get the whole concept.